# maintaing font and font color state in C# .net winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts

I have created a small demo in C# .Net Win-form, below is screenshot of my demo.
[image]

Above screenshot have two buttons with font color and font named, when I clicked on Font Color then appear a color dialog box and we can give the label color by select any color from color dialog box and when I clicked on Font button then appear a font dialog box which is help to give the font style, font size and font family. It works perfectly. But my problem is that I want to maintain font and font color state (means after restarting this project maintain the given font and font color).

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to persist the values across runs.